# Set footer at child inside the expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have created the expandable listview.That list view contain parent and child.I want to add the footer inside the child layout.The footer set properly in !st parent.If expand the second parent the footer position get changed.How to set footer at bottom for all parent.`

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public static ArrayList<Child> ch_list= new ArrayList<Child>();

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;
    Button button;
    CheckinAdapter adapter;
    String status;
    private ArrayList<Child> movielist = new ArrayList<Child>();
    public  ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }



    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {



            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


//            if(childPosition ==0)
//            {
//                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
//            }
//
//            //Here is the ListView of the ChildView
//            if(childPosition>0 && childPosition<getChildrenCount(groupPosition)-1)
//            {


                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);


                TextView  amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
                TextView food_item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_item);

                TextView item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);

                String fooditem=child.getfood_name();
                String getamount=child.getfood_total();
                String getitem_count=child.getfood_count();
                String foodiem="foodiem--"+fooditem+"amount--"+getamount+"count--"+getitem_count;

                Log.d("fooditem--",foodiem);

                if (child.getfood_name() != null) {
                    if (!child.getfood_name().equals("null")) {
                        food_item.setText(fooditem);
                    }
                }
                if (child.getfood_total() != null) {
                    if (!child.getfood_total().equals("null")) {
                        amount.setText(getamount);
                    }
                }
                if (child.getfood_count() != null) {
                    if (!child.getfood_count().equals("null")) {
                        item_count.setText(getitem_count);
                    }}

            if(childPosition == getChildrenCount(groupPosition)-1)
            {



                LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_list, null);
                TextView total_itemamount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_itemamount);
                TextView servicetax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.servicetax);
                TextView grand_total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grand_total);


                if (child.getsubtotal() != null) {
                    if (!child.getsubtotal().equals("null")) {
                        total_itemamount.setText(child.getsubtotal());

                    }
                }
                if (child.getservicetax() != null) {
                    if (!child.getservicetax().equals("null")) {
                        servicetax.setText(child.getservicetax());

                    }
                }
                if (child.getgrand_total() != null) {
                    if (!child.getgrand_total().equals("null")) {
                        grand_total.setText(child.getgrand_total());

                    }
                }
            }


        }
      return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);

            TextView order_id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
            TextView time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            TextView items = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.items);
            Button delivered = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delivered);
            Button accept = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
            Button decline = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.decline);

           // order_id,order_items,order_status,order_time
            if (group.getorder_id() != null) {
                if (!group.getorder_id().equals("null")) {
                    order_id.setText(group.getorder_id());
                }
            }
    ;


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

`